# Sql Server FETCH NEXT x ROWS ONLY slow when number of rows to select is less then x

Tags: sql-server, pagination

So I have the following problem. When selecting data with `FETCH NEXT x ROWS ONLY` clause the query takes too much time if there actually are less rows to select then x. The select query contains multiple `INNER JOINS` multiple `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE` clause with `IN` keyword in it. So the query takes from 0.3-0.8 seconds, Suppose there are 15 rows to select with some predicate, if I added the following lines to my query `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;` the query execution time increases dramatically to 6-10 seconds if I change 100 to like 10 (or anything less or equal to then time is the same 0.5 seconds average, so the problem occurred when there are less rows to select then specified in `FETCH NEXT` statement. DB is Sql Server 2012

Comment: can you add the actual sql code

Comment: After some basic tests, I can't reproduce any significant delays when the rows to return is less than the remaining rows, so I suggest you add your query as there's likely to be something in there that is causing the delay. If you can create an example in sql fiddle that demonstrates the issue that would be even better.

Comment: I would start with comparing execution plans for three variants of your query. Most likely it will be different, so you'll need to analyse it and figure out why optimizer generates a bad plan in certain case. The second thing I would do is rebuild all relevant indexes and update all statistics, because obsolete statistics can easily result in bad plans.